# RejectedExecutionException when executing tasks using threadpool : JAVA

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Threadpool rejecting tasks while submitting. Threadpool size is fixed and it is 8. Even though i am not sumbitting the tasks more than 8 it is rejecting. I tried using the blocking queue but it is not helping me.

Here is my code snippet

```
try {
            List<Future> tasks = new ArrayList<Future>();
            ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessingJobMeta meta = process.getPJM();
            List<CuratedInput> cil = meta.getCuratedInputList();
            for (final CuratedInput ci : cil) {
                for (final Preperation prep : Preperation.values()) {
                    for (final Export export : Export.values()) {
                        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                LOGGER.info("Executing.................." + prep.toString() );
                                LOGGER.info("Executing.................." + export.toString());
                                PreperationFactory.getPreperation(prep.toString(), ci);
                                ExportFactory.getExport(export.toString(), ci);
                            }
                        };
//                      tpe.submit(runnable);
                        tasks.add((Future) tpe.submit(runnable));

                        for (Future p : tasks) {
                            LOGGER.info("---------------inside the futures for loop------------");
                            LOGGER.info("Result of the future executed ------> " + p.get());
                        }

                        tpe.shutdown();

                        while (!tpe.isShutdown()) {

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your shutting down the pool within the loop and attemting to add more threads to an already shutdown pool. place these lines out of the loop

```
tpe.shutdown();

while (!tpe.isShutdown()) {

}
```

something like this

```
List<Future> tasks = new ArrayList<Future>();
        ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessingJobMeta meta = process.getPJM();
        List<CuratedInput> cil = meta.getCuratedInputList();
        for (final CuratedInput ci : cil) {
            .....
        }

        tpe.shutdown();
        while (!tpe.isShutdown()) {

        }
```

Please try that